# How do I make an input password only get validated if it is filled in while editing a user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, passwords, validation

I am using Jquery with Validator plugin.

What I want to happen: When I popup a modal to edit a user I only want the password to be validated IF there is a password entered. I have this part covered. But if I begin to enter a password and then ultimately decide to erase it and move on it is still getting validated even though it is empty.

So if I never touch the password it doesn't get validated and this is what I want. If I do type and then remove what I typed it still tries to validate. This is not what I want. I want it to realize I decided against entering a new password for the user and again skip attempting to validate it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#epassword").focusout(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
      $("#editgirlform").validate({
        rules: {
          password: {
          required: false,
          pwcheck: true,
          minlength: 6
        }
      },
        messages: {
          password: {
          required: "Password required",
          pwcheck: "Password must have at least 1 lowercase letter and 1 number!",
          minlength: "The password must be at least 6 characters!"
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

$.validator.addMethod("pwcheck", function(value) {
     return /^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!-@._*]*$/.test(value) // consists of only these
            && /[a-z]/.test(value) // has a lowercase letter
           && /\d/.test(value) // has a digit
   });
   }

Comment: So, the interesting thing is that when I create a demo of this, your code seems to work just fine.   Take a look at this [http://jsbin.com/ebaBUto/1/edit].   It's basically a simplified version of what you've got.   Even if you type something in the box and erase it, it says that no validation is necessary.

Comment: I added the actual validator plugin and other info required to do it in jsbin with my actual functions. [http://jsbin.com/ebaBUto/2/edit?html,js,output](http://jsbin.com/ebaBUto/2/edit?html,js,output) It doesn't stop validating if you clear out the password.